# Getting classes through a String

Tags: java, class, object, reflection, invoke

I'm trying to get classes through a String and the path to the class through a String array like this:

```
public void getClass(String name, String[] className){
        try {
            Class current=Game.class;
            if(className!=null)
            for(int i2=0;i2<className.length;i2++){
                for(int i=0;i<current.getClasses().length;i++){
                        if(className[i2].equals(current.getClasses()[i].getSimpleName())){
                            current=current.getClasses()[i];
                            System.out.println(current.getSimpleName());
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
            Field f=current.getDeclaredField(name.trim());
            f.setAccessible(true);
            return f.get(current);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But when I try to run it with the parameters name:"health" and className:{"player"} it should work, as the class Game contains the class "player" and player contains the integer "health". Instead I get this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field Game.Game$Player.health to java.lang.Class
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.get(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
at Game.Game$Enemy.callVariable(Game.java:1384)
at Game.Game$Enemy.callMethods(Game.java:1357)
at Game.Game$Enemy.update(Game.java:1295)
at Game.Game$EnemyContainer.update(Game.java:1235)
at Game.Game.doFrameInGame(Game.java:563)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: could you post code of game and player classes?

Comment: what do you mean "class Game contains the class "player"" I guess inheritance

Comment: Is `player` an inner class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a syntax error in the code that you posted, because it's a void method and you're trying to return a value.

According to your error log, I assume that you're trying to return an int value when you invoke

```
return f.get(current)
```

But the variable `current` is not an instance of the class that contains the field f, instead it's a class object, i.e, it's a reference to the Game class or any other class that matches in your loop.

In order to have it working, `current` should point to a concrete object (instance of Game class for example)